# How Discord checks if a Javascript File is a folder on client side?

Tags: javascript, file, validation, discord, drag-and-drop

I notice that Discord can detect if you drop a folder without sending any validation request to a server, all in the client. How can I do that?

When a file is submitted from an `<input type="file">` then there is no problem, because it can't select folders, but on a drag-and-drop system you can drop anything and I'm looking for a way to detect folders because it's weird how if you drop a folder, let's say `folderExample` you get a `File` object with the property `type=""`, BUT when you drop the same folder with a name like `folderExample.jpg` now the type is `"image/jpeg"`!!!

There is how I'm handling the file dropping, hope some can help

```js
const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  
    const {files} = e.dataTransfer;
    console.log('Dropped files:', files)
  };
```